# Matlab. Absolute markersize

Tags: matlab, plot

I know I can plot a dot and select its size with the word 'markersize' like this

```
plot(0,0,'.','markersize',50) %Dot centered in (0,0)
```

The size of the dot produced does not change if we amplify the plot. It always seems to have the same size to our eye. I would like to produce dots (or circles) with a real radius, so that when the image is amplified it appears bigger. What are my options?

Comment: Are you have image processing Toolbox?

Answer (score 0):

Use rectangle command with curvature [1 1] it will draw circles with relative radius.